# Mysql get results that have more matching on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
vehicle   colour    animal    softdrink    
car       red       snake     cola
jeep      blue      dog       pepsi
```

Now I would pass to query these parameters:

```
jeep   blue   snake  pepsi
```

How can I create a query that returns rows in order of how many columns have in common with my parameters?

In this example the second row must return to the first place because 3 columns are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the parameters apply to each column, you can just do:

```
select t.*
from t
order by ( (vehicle = @vehicle) +
           (colour = @colour) +
           (animal = @animal) +
           (softdrink = @softdrink)
         ) desc;
```

This uses a convenient MySQL shorthand where booleans are treated as numbers in a numeric context.  In other databases, you would need to use explicit `case` expressions.

Comment: Can you explain me this syntax (@ and +) ?

Comment: @Ilario . . . The `@` is to represent a variable -- however you decide to pass parameters in (I guess `?` would be more typical).  The `+` is explained:  it is addition.

Comment: thanks, I try it as soon as possible and let you know

Comment: is it possible to return the rows that have minimum two columns equal?

Comment: @Ilario . . . You can put a similar expression in the `where` with `>= 2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon